# Replacing jQuery code with Javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know a little bit **jQuery**, and even though it is still javascript, I do not know how to convert the following code to pure Javascript:

```
$('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]')
    .attr('href','http://myurl.com/803-2');
```

How would I do that?

The reason why I am doing this is because I am using a Wordpress theme...whenever I include the **jQuery** library, it breaks many things on my site, when I don't include the jquery library, no jquery code runs...

Comment: There are two parts to the problem.  Selecting the element, and setting the attribute.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference/ is very useful

Comment: For the part that selects by attribute (`[href="http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector

Comment: About the jQuery issue on wordpress, It could be because of conflicts with another lib: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ or maybe because it uses a different version. Check this, it might solve the problem.

Comment: thank you guys, All your answers are very insightful and useful

Comment: @ericosg: Thank you, very cool article- I was wondering if there is something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ is just an alias for jQuery.  You could just use:

```
jQuery('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]').attr('href','http://myurl.com/803-2');
```

or else wrap the code in a self executing function passing in jQuery like:

```
(function($){
     $('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]').attr('href','http://myurl.com/803-2');
})(jQuery);
```

If you really want to go down the pure js route, then take a look at:

```
document.getElementById()
```

and

```
element.setAttribute()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to drop support for Internet Explorer 7, you could do

```
var i, elems = document.querySelectorAll('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]');

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   elems[i].href = 'http://myurl.com/803-2';
}
```

Otherwise, I'm afraid you are better off using a library.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found the real source of the problem.

Comment: Yes...it was as simple as wrapping my code inside: jQuery(function ($) {});...But knowing how to do it in pure js is good to know anyways...

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you might want to just try to resolve the library conflicts.

To answer your question, here is a possibility:

```
var elements = document
    .getElementById('breadcrumbs')
    .getElementsByClassName('category'); //Not supported below IE9 :-(

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].href == "http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products") {
        elements[i].setAttribute('href', "http://myurl.com/803-2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's selectors are based on sizzle: http://sizzlejs.com/ Maybe you can include that library? If not, the first part of your problem is quite difficult.

The second part is easy:

```
myElement.setAttribute('href','http://myurl.com/803-2');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to include jQuery library for url change. We need following functions

```
function getByClassName( className , selector ) {
    selector = selector || document;

    if( selector.getElementsByClassName ) {
        return selector.getElementsByClassName( className );
    }

    var els = [];

    var childs = selector.getElementsByTagName( '*' );

    for( var i = 0, j = childs.length; i < j; i++ ) {
        if( childs[i].className.indexOf( className ) > -1 ) {
            els.push( childs[i] );
        }
    }
    return els;
};

function changeUrl( els ,  url , newUrl  ){

    for( var i = 0; i < els.length ; i++ ){

        if ( els[i].href == url ) {
                els[i].href = newUrl ;
        }
    }

}
```

and call the function

```
changeUrl ( 
  getByClassName( 'category' , document.getElementById('breadcrumbs')  ) , 
  "http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products" , 
  "http://myurl.com/803-2"
);
```

or If you are using jQuery library .. use this

```
(function( JQ ){

    JQ('#breadcrumbs .category[href="'
        + 'http://asksomeone.co.za/category/products"]')
       .attr('href',"http://myurl.com/803-2");

})( jQuery );
```