# InnerHTML of a div

Tags: javascript, html

If you want to retrieve the innerHTML of a div (seen beneath) without using getElementByID (considering this website has several div's with 'quote' as an id), but by referring to the 'field name' (field="bid"). How would you do that?

```
<div nowrap="nowrap" id="quote" class="realtimeDetailLayer" source="lightstreamer" 
style="display:inline" table="LS_ProductDetails_TabID" item="X0000010600NL0010379129"
field="bid">0,28</div>
```

I want to retrieve the information from an existing website. See beneath. Here you can see that several div's have the same ID

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;width:auto;padding:8px 0px;"><nobr>Ref.</nobr>:</td>
    <td class="ext04" style="white-space:nowrap;width:12%;font-weight:bold;">
    EUR
      <strong><div nowrap=nowrap id="quote" class="realtimeDetailLayer" source="lightstreamer" style="display:inline" table="LS_ProductDetails_TabID" item="X0000010600NL0010379129" field="reference">350,85
      </div></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;width:auto;padding:8px 0px;"><nobr>Bied</nobr>:</td>
    <td class="ext04" style="white-space:nowrap;width:12%;font-weight:bold;">
    EUR 
      <div nowrap=nowrap id="quote" class="realtimeDetailLayer" source="lightstreamer" style="display:inline" table="LS_ProductDetails_TabID" item="X0000010600NL0010379129" field="bid">0,28</div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;width:auto;padding:8px 0px;">
      <nobr>Laat</nobr>:
    </td>
    <td class="ext04" style="white-space:nowrap;width:12%;font-weight:bold;">
    EUR
      <div nowrap=nowrap id="quote" class="realtimeDetailLayer" source="lightstreamer" style="display:inline" table="LS_ProductDetails_TabID" item="X0000010600NL0010379129" field="ask">0,29
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;width:auto;padding:8px 0px;"><nobr>%</nobr>:</td>
    <td class="ext04" style="white-space:nowrap;width:12%;font-weight:bold;">
      <div nowrap=nowrap id="quote" class="realtimeDetailLayer" source="lightstreamerGeneratedValues" style="display:inline" table="LS_ProductDetails_TabID" item="X0000010600NL0010379129" field="midchangepercent"><span class="extNegative"><nobr>-50,88 %</nobr></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector

Comment: @Shiju you *can* have the same ID's on a page, but you *shouldn't* for this very reason.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique (the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) is quite clear about that). You should *never* have tags with the same ID in one page. If you need a name for grouping several tags use the `class` attribute.

Comment: @RemarkLima http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 ids should be unique to the document they are used on

Comment: @RemarkLima And even if you really accidentally have two `<div id="quote"></div><div id="quote"></div>`, jQuery will always give you the first one, `alert($('#quote').length)` will tell you it's 1.

Comment: @RemarkLima what has jQuery to do with it?

Comment: Good lord, does anyone **not** know what **ID** stands for?

Comment: Guys, the point is you physically can have non-unique ID's, the page will be served and the browser will render it. However, you shouldn't as they're no longer an ID at that point *sigh* So, while you can all shout "YOU MUSTN'T HAVE THE SAME ID'S ON A PAGE!", people can, and do incorrectly, so the question is still valid - even if the answer is to correct your code so that all ID's are unique.

Comment: why not using field values as id, and then have unique id values?

Comment: @Michal I suggested jQuery simply in that you can loop through the DOM easier with it. No other reason.

Comment: @RemarkLima still you're missing the main problem. Duplicate IDs are invalid and one should never try to get around it by using alternative methods.

Comment: @Michal Yes, I totally agree with you. I'm not missing the problem - in this instance the answer is to fix the code creating duplicate ID's. But for people to say "you can't have duplicate ID's" is incorrect, as there is no errors generated from this, the browser doesn't reject the HTML, so to the *layman* duplicate ID's do not pose a problem per se. Hence my initial stance, you *can* have duplicate ID's, but you shouldn't. Obviously, duplicate ID's in a complied language result in an error meaning that you can't have duplicate ID's.

Comment: @RemarkLima Theoretically you're right, but this is basically what professionals call "bad practice" and one should be avoid it like the plague. Browsers "allow" it because to support the ignorance of some low quality developers, but http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 says clearly that "This name must be unique in a document."

Comment: It's possible that the OP doesn't have access to change the HTML they're trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply parsing the DOM that is by getting parent and children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  if (els[i].field == 'bid') {
    //do whatever with the bid element here.
  }
}
```

This gets all the `divs` and checks the `field` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for the worst case scenario where you don't have any way to have unique ids for the elements

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
function getQuoteHtml(key){
    var i;
    for(i =0 ; i < divs.length; i++){
        if(divs[i].getAttribute('field') == key){
            return divs[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m3ZhM/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a css selector to do that

```
document.querySelectorAll('[field="bid"]');
```