# how to find specific particular attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, select, append

```
<div __jx__id="___$_15" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
```

I would like to modify the above div by adding display:block to the style using javascript

```
<div __jx__id="___$_15" style="display:block;position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
```

I tried using

```
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute))
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}
```

`getAllElementsWithAttribute('__jx__id="___$_15);`

adapted from

[Get elements by attribute when querySelectorAll is not available without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector)

the selector itself is not working let alone add the additonal `display:block` to the div

Answer (score 1):

The name of your attribute is `__jx__id` and the value is `___$_15`.

so try: `getAllElementsWithAttribute("__jx__id")`;

If you also want to filter by the value of the attribute then you'll need to pass it in seperately: `getAllElementsWithAttributeAndValue("__jx__id", "___$_15");`

Answer (score 0):

A lot easier with jQuery:

```
$("div[__jx__id]").css({display:block});
```

or even

```
$("div[__jx__id]").show();
```