# Select children in JavaScript because I can't use jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using jQuery to find out if there is an li with the attribute of data-val="-1" inside the #mainNavigation div. In jQuery this works fine, but I need to do the same thing in JavaScript. What I can't figure out is how to drill down the way it's done using selectors in jQuery.

```
if($('#mainNavigation ul li ul li[data-val="-1"]')){
   $("#mainNavigation").css("padding-left" , "10px");
};

<div id="mainNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li data-val="-1">Title</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The jQuery method that you have is incorrect anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get elements by attribute selector w/ native JavaScript w/o querySelectorAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector)

Comment: @Aguardientico: OP isn't asking how to do it without `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @BlueSkies but is asking how to select in pure javascript so in that question is the answer.

Comment: @Aguardientico: Sure, but using `querySelector[All]` is an answer too.

Comment: @BlueSkies you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.querySelector()`:

```
if (document.querySelector('#mainNavigation ul li ul li[data-val="-1"]')){
   // ...
}
```

---

Or if you don't need to be so specific about the level, then this:

```
if (document.querySelector('#mainNavigation li[data-val="-1"]')){
   // ...
}
```

---

Or without using `querySelector`:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('mainNavigation').getElementsByTagName("li");
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (lis[i].getAttribute("data-val") === "-1") {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The 3rd option worked for me, thanks! Aren't the first two options using a jQuery selector by using #mainNavigation?

Comment: @ech: No, they're using a Selectors API selector. This is native JavaScript code, not jQuery. It's what jQuery uses under the hood.