# AngularJS - Find Element with attribute

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I've learned that I can find elements in the DOM using queries like the following:

```
var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'));
var e = angular.element(elem.querySelector('.classname'));
```

This is useful for finding elements by ID, or by CSS class name. However, I need to be able to find an element using a different approach. I have an element that looks like the following:

```
<div my-directive class='myContainer'>...</div>
```

I can't query on 'myContainer' because of how much its reused. For that reason, I would like to find any element with the attribute 'my-directive'. How do I search the DOM and find any element that makes use of 'my-directive'?

Comment: Asking this question suggests you're not quite using Angular how it's intended. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree that you're not supposed to use Angular in this method typically. However, I need to find a component that I've built that may or may not be on the page. That is why I'm trying to search the DOM.

Comment: I found this question when I had exactly the same problem. To me, it seemed simplest just to add an ID to the element. Is there any reason not to do that and to seek another solution?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Rather than querying the DOM for elements (which isn't very angular see ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)) you should perform your DOM manipulation within your directive. The element is available to you in your link function.

So in your myDirective

```
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.html('Hello world');
    }
}
```

If you must perform the query outside of the directive then it would be possible to use querySelectorAll in modern browers

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("[my-directive]"));
```

however you would need to use jquery to support IE8 and backwards

```
angular.element($("[my-directive]"));
```

or write your own method as demonstrated here [Get elements by attribute when querySelectorAll is not available without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector)

Comment: I'm familiar with that approach. However, in this case I really need to query the DOM. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Be careful with `angular.element(document.querySelectorAll())`. This searches from the document root, which may not be what you want. My answer below shows how to find an element within the scope of an element with a controller, which a good developer tries to avoid, but sometimes can't. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24275151/1450294

Answer (score 13):

You haven't stated where you're looking for the element. If it's within the scope of a controller, it is possible, despite the chorus you'll hear about it not being the 'Angular Way'. The chorus is right, but sometimes, in the real world, it's unavoidable. (If you disagree, get in touch—I have a challenge for you.)

If you pass [`$element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) into a controller, like you would `$scope`, you can use its `find()` function. Note that, in the jQueryLite included in Angular, `find()` will only locate tags by name, not attribute. However, if you include the full-blown jQuery in your project, all the functionality of [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) can be used, including finding by attribute.

So, for this HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <div>
        <div name='foo' class='myElementClass'>this one</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This AngularJS code should work:

```
angular.module('MyClient').controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$element',
    '$log',
    function ($scope, $element, $log) {

        // Find the element by its class attribute, within your controller's scope
        var myElements = $element.find('.myElementClass');

        // myElements is now an array of jQuery DOM elements

        if (myElements.length == 0) {
            // Not found. Are you sure you've included the full jQuery?
        } else {
            // There should only be one, and it will be element 0
            $log.debug(myElements[0].name); // "foo"
        }

    }
]);
```

Comment: For this to work you need to rely on the full jQuery rather than the jQueryLite that is embedded in AngularJS.   Not stating this distinction can be frustrating for those (me) not willing to take a dependency on jQuery but still learning limitations of jQueryLite

Comment: I apologise for the frustration. I guess the project I was working on did have jQuery included—I didn't think it did, but now that I've researched it, I've found the docs state that find() only searches for tags by name in jQueryLite. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Considering that in Angular programming, we should not manipulate DOM directly, is this anti-pattern to use $element in a controller?

Comment: @gm2008: You could argue it that way. The second and third sentences in the answer are my counterargument.

Answer (score 11):

Your use-case isn't clear. However, if you are certain that you need this to be based on the DOM, and not model-data, then this is a way for one directive to have a reference to all elements with another directive specified on them.

The way is that the child directive can `require` the parent directive. The parent directive can expose a method that allows direct directive to register their element with the parent directive. Through this, the parent directive can access the child element(s). So if you have a template like:

```
<div parent-directive>
  <div child-directive></div>
  <div child-directive></div>
</div>
```

Then the directives can be coded like:

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function($window) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      var registeredElements = [];
      this.registerElement = function(childElement) {
        registeredElements.push(childElement);
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: '^parentDirective',
    template: '<span>Child directive</span>',
    link: function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, parentController) {
      parentController.registerElement(iElement);
    }
   };
});
```

You can see this in action at http://plnkr.co/edit/7zUgNp2MV3wMyAUYxlkz?p=preview