# How to get element by classname or id

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find the element in html by angularjs.

Here is the html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary multi-files" type="button">
   <span>Choose multiple files</span>
</button>
<br/><br/>
<input ng-file-select type="file" multiple  style="display: none"/><br/>
```

I am trying to get the button element by class name multi-files, then I tried

```
var multibutton = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName(".multi-files"));
```

But it does not work, and tried `element.find` but it only works for tag.

Is there any function that can get element by id or classname in angularjs?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801843/angularjs-find-element-with-attribute

Comment: You don't even have to create a directive.. you could simply add a handler like ng-click. Worst case, if you really want to get the element, you can always use jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is a function on the DOM Document. It is neither a jQuery nor a jqLite function.

Don't add the period before the class name when using it:

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("multi-files");
```

Wrap it in jqLite (or jQuery if jQuery is loaded before Angular):

```
var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
```

If you want to select from the `element` in a directive's link function you need to access the DOM reference instead of the the jqLite reference - `element[0]` instead of `element`:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

  var elementResult = element[0].getElementsByClassName('multi-files');
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `document.querySelector` function (need the period here if selecting by class):

```
var queryResult = element[0].querySelector('.multi-files');
var wrappedQueryResult = angular.element(queryResult);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/AOvO47ebEvrtpXeIzYOH?p=preview

Comment: It may be worth noting that inside the link function, element.childElementCount may be 0 because angular hasn't had the chance to create the elements yet, so you should be prepared to deal with no results for element[0].getElement...

Answer (score 28):

You don't have to add a `.` in `getElementsByClassName`, i.e.

```
var multibutton = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("multi-files"));
```

However, when using `angular.element`, you do have to use jquery style selectors:

```
angular.element('.multi-files');
```

should do the trick.

Also, from [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) "If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite.""

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i tried that, but error says undefined function

Comment: It might or might not work, yes. Please check my answer now (made an edit) and you'll probably know what to do.

Comment: If the function is undefined you probably didn't load jquery. jqlite (which is used if you didn't load jquery as @Ashesh mentioned) doesn't have all the functions that jquery has, and getElementsByClassName is one of them.

Comment: angular.element('multi-files'); won't work. You do need the period.

Comment: var multibutton = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("multi-files"));

Answer (score 21):

@tasseKATT's Answer is great, but if you don't want to make a directive, why not use `$document`?

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
  var dumb = function (id) {
  var queryResult = $document[0].getElementById(id)
  var wrappedID = angular.element(queryResult);
  return wrappedID;
};
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/EzH7Me0LPEOuLhgptLNr?p=info)

Comment: `angular.element('#Your element id')` does the same job.

Comment: It's giving this error in angular 1.5.8. "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite"

Answer (score -4):

If you want to find the button only by its class name and using jQLite only, you can do like below:

```
var myListButton = $document.find('button').filter(function() {
    return angular.element(this).hasClass('multi-files');
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This isn't using angular and jquery, also, incorrect statment, you CAN indeed use jquery to replace jqlite.

This is the correct way to do this in an angular environment, without going down to the vanilla javascript element ($document[0]).