# Accessing element in an Angular directive with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a form inside a nested directive (in an Ionic/Angular project)

```
<ion-content class="scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header">
  <recipe-form>
    <form id="example-form" action="#" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </form>
  </recipe-form>
<div>
```

But I cannot access this for via jQuery.

I tried the following without success:

```
$(function () {
  #$('#example-form')
  #angular.element(document.querySelector('#example-form'))
  #angular.element.find('#example-form') 
  #angular.element.find('example-form')
  #angular.element(document.querySelector('example-form')) 
}
```

I also have found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id) questions, and almost all of them are solved by using syntax `angular.element(document.querySelector(<element id>))`

But for me it gives a blank array `[]`

I'm loading my js file in the `head` section and after jQuery.

**Update**

However, this following method I have in the same file for button click works as expected

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.next', function(e){
    arr = [];
    arr = $('.card.recipe-slider');
    current_card = $(this).closest('.card')[0];
    id = current_card.dataset.id;

    if (validateInput(current_card)){
      $(arr[id]).addClass('active');
      $(current_card).removeClass('active');
    } else {
    }

  })

});
```

Comment: Does it work if you put your scripts at the bottom of the `body`?

Comment: Where is `$(function () { ... }` located and when is it executed?

Comment: @rwacarter, sorry for the late reply, No .. it doesnot work ;(.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to find the element before it actually exists in the DOM.

Comment: @tasseKATT, hi, its in a separate js file and its loading when the page loads. (I checked with chrome terminal)

Comment: Will the form be visible after load?

Comment: @tasseKATT, yes form is visible , and you are correct, form is not visible when the js loads initially. but my understand is `$(function () { ... }` should take care of that, or am I missing something ? .. thanks for the reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69349/discussion-between-tassekatt-and-sameera207).

Comment: @sameera207 Your update proves that the element does not exist in the DOM at the time you are trying to find it.. What are you wanting to do with the `$('#example-form')` once you have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution for my question. This main point I was missing is, you cannot directly access `form` elements via `JQuery` inside a directive.

So with the outstanding help of @tasseKATT and with the following [article](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/) I was able to get it running

Following is my final code (I was trying to add [Jquery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) plugin)

```
angular.module('directive.recipeForm',[])
  .directive('recipeForm', function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: false,
       link: function(scope, element){
         var form = $("#example-form");
         form.children("div").steps({
           headerTag: "h3",
           bodyTag: "section",
           transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
           onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
           {

           },
           onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
           {

           },
           onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
           {

           }
         });
       },
       controller: 'newRecipeCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'templates/directives/recipe_form.html'
    }
  });
```