# Ionic: Getting element from template with id

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I notice that when Ionic renders the same template (for multiple views), I am forced into a situation where I have multiple elements of the same html id.

Hence, if I just plainly use `document.getElementById(id)`, I find myself in situations where I do not get the element I want.

(I want the element inside the current rendered view, and not the element inside the template of some other view currently the user is not in)

How should I get around this? Is there a way to get an element from within the boundaries of the current view being rendered?

Comment: you can use jqlite ,this is might help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id