# Get Angular input handle when accessing element by id

Tags: angularjs, forms

Angular offers great possibilities for reading the status of an input field, like `$dirty`, `$touched` and so on. However, as far as I found out, that works only when accessing an input element by its name, like `$scope.formName.inputFieldName`.

But I need to access an input element defined in a directive template inside the directive's controller by the element's ID (and without the form name). Whatever I try, I don't get the special input form handles.
Something like

```
var myElement = $document[0].getElementById('my_id');
console.log(angular.element(myElement));
```

doesn't work. I get the DOM element itself, wrapped inside generic object context, but not the input handles Angular offers.

Comment: Found that one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id in Ari's answer. However, it doesn't seem to matter. Using vanilla JavaScript 'document.getElementById' gives exactly the same result.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you tried the element parameter from the link function?

Comment: That doesn't exist. I generate dozens of input elements inside this directive template. And I want to access one single of them in the directive's controller function.

Comment: Did you try `angular.element(myElement).controller("ngModel")`?

Comment: @georgeawg That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `angular.element(myElement).controller("ngModel")` to access the model controller of an input element.

For more information, see [AngularJS element function API Reference -- jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)