# I couldn't find element by angular.element('#id')

Tags: angularjs

I used this code to find my elements in the angular controller:

```
var el = angular.element('#id');
```

But this doesn't work. why?

Is it true that I use *jQuery* to find my elements ?

I confused my code doesn't work any more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by classname or id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("id"));
```

Comment: It works but why `angular.element('#id')` worked before?

Comment: I don't know, always I use this.

Comment: i think i figured out your problem. you used to earlier versions of **angularjs 1.x** before and now you're working with newer one.this function was changed after some versions

Comment: Thank you @Majid Parvin. your comment help me more than this answer.I have updated recently.