# How to select element by classname and iterate through those objects in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am new to angularJs, i have a function in my angular controller as

```
$scope.addPrimaryClass = function () {
        var weekDayBtn = $(".weekdayButton");
        weekDayBtn.addClass("btn-white").removeClass("btn-primary");
        $.each(weekDayBtn,function (index) {
            if($(this).val()==$scope.weekly){
                $(this).addClass("btn-primary").removeClass("btn-white");
            }
        })
    };
```

In view i have :

```
<div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="7" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Sun</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="1" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Mon</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary weekdayButton" type="button" value="2" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Tue</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="3" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Wed</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="4" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Thu</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="5" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Fri</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-white weekdayButton" type="button" value="6" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);">Sat</button>
                    </div>
```

The code in **addPrimaryClass** works as required in console since i can use normal jquery there, but the code doesn't work in angular itself. Basically, i want to change the css of buttons according to one of the scope value. Please help!!!

Comment: is it jquery or is it angular?

Comment: @guradio AngularJS has jQuery lite under the bonnet accessible via [`angular.element()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) But as it's jQuery lite there are some restrictions as stated in the documentation.

Comment: This is in angular, i want the similar functionality as in jquery.

Comment: @PrabinUpreti Read the documentation for [angular.element()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-class` directive to apply the classes depending on what the scope variable is. For example:

```
<button class="btn weekdayButton" type="button" value="7" ng-click="weekdayClicked($event);" ng-class="($(this).val()==$scope.weekly) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-white'">Sun</button>
```

There are several ways using the `ng-class` directive. Please have a look at the documentation and decide what's best for you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

---

On a separate note, you might want to remove all jQuery from your Angular code :)