# DOM get name element by input id

Tags: html, dom

My html code looks like this

```
<input type="text" class="bk-i bk-fill-parent" id="loginField" name="loginSGizS" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20">
```

I want to get what's inside `name=" "` which is loginSGizS, now I see the obvious way is by input id, but I can't quite figure it out

UPDATE: I'm using this inside a php file with curl and I kind of need to keep everything within that file. What I tried so far

```
<?php       $home = curl('https://website.com'); $oDom = new simple_html_dom(); $oDom->load($home); $elements = $oDom->getElementById("loginField"); foreach($elements as $element){ echo $element->getAttribute('name'); }
```

UPDATE: I used regex `$pattern = '/<input (?=[^>]* id="loginField" name=["]([^"]*)|)/ms';` and it works, thank y'all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by classname or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("loginField").getAttribute("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get it by attr method:

```
var name = $("#id").attr("name");
```

Comment: i'm using this in a php file with curl so i need to make it happen inside the same file my only hope is dom