# jQuery attribute "[something*=something]" selector in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am curious if pure javascript can replace this jQuery selector for IE7 and greater..

Do people simply change the markup and select using a class or is their away of selecting this using pure javascript

```
<h1 rel="xxxexternalxxx">Attribute Contains</h1>

var arrinput = $('[rel*="external"])
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get elements by attribute selector w/ native JavaScript w/o querySelectorAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector)

Comment: The type of selector is different to that question, this is not a basic attribute selector like the link you suggest.

Comment: It's not exactly a dup, but you can use that helper then filter the result by looping and comparing with regex, or substr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getElementsByAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342661/670396), then loop and filter:

```
var rels = getElementsByAttribute('rel');
var attr = 'external';

var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<rels.length; i++) {
  if (rels[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf(attr) > -1) {
    result.push(rels[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a great solution, Ill test and post the complete fiddle later today. Thanks again elclanrs

Comment: See my update http://jsfiddle.net/fgs2u/1/. Check the console, it it'll give you info on what's wrong, that's how I found out.