# Javascript handle 2 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use data attribute in my html 
like
 `<div id="userlist" data-user="A.A.M"></div>`
then I need to alert the data-user
I used

```
var userlist = document.getElementById("userlist");

var show = userlist.getAttribute("data-user");
alert(show);
```

My question is how to handle many data-user in the html like

`<div id="userlist" data-user="A.A.M"></div> 
<div id="userlist2" data-user="A.A.M2"></div>`
to alert A.A.M and A.A.M2

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You want something that will give you all the elements with that attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available. Then you will need to loop through them all.

Comment: Please can you show me an example as I tried and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you know how to alert 1, alert 2:

alert at the same time:

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("userlist").getAttribute("data-user");
var data2 =  document.getElementById("userlist2").getAttribute("data-user");

var data = data1 +"\n" +  data2; //"\n" can be other separators you like

alert(data)
```

if you have many of them, you can use jQuery: 
add this in your  , before any other js code.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

then :

```
  $("div[id^=userlist]").each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("data-user"));
    });
```

Comment: This is a basic way. I need to be dona automaticly

Comment: The jquery way is automatic method. try it. @user3530661

Comment: It didn't work and the error in console is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) "

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: No I am still beginner :(

Answer (score 2):

You could select your elements by attribute.

```
$("div[data-user]").each(function() {
    var user = $(this).data("user");
    alert(user);
});
```

If you have multiple attributes per element (`<div data-user='something' data-another='another'></div>`), you can also access those in the same way:

```
$("div[data-user]").each(function() {
    var user = $(this).data("user");
    var another = $(this).data("another");
    alert(user + ", another: " + another);
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).data("user")` try `this.getAttribute("data-user")` or with jQuery `$(this).attr("data-user")`.

Comment: @user3530661 Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/munr/Tk7xL/

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getElementById` on both should work. If you want to iterate you can try to use `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName`. If you want to select any arbitrary element with the attribute `data-user`, you can either use `querySelectorAll`, or check out jQuery, and use `$("[data-user]")` as a selector.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I need the javascript to automatically allert 2 time 1 with A.A.M and the other with A.A.M2, Can you show me an example please