# read table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried many ways to read and reach table elements.I have a table in html and ı need to get PRODUCT column values.but I couldnt.Because I cant reach column by column values.
Could you pls help?I will make some calculates accoridng to product names and dates,diffminutes etc.thanks alot.

```
<table id="playsql-0" class="playsql tablesorter" data-uid="0" data-query-editor-url="/confluence/playsql-base-plugin/query-editor.action?key=PDOQA&amp;queryId=35">
    <tbody class="">
        <tr id="playsql-0-7" data-row-id="7">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="7" data-row-id="7">7</th>                                                                                                
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19502">19502</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="7">7</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 07:00:00">2014-07-16 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 07:50:00">2014-07-16 07:50:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 07:00:00">2014-07-16 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 07:45:00">2014-07-16 07:45:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="45">45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-5" data-row-id="5">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="5" data-row-id="5">5</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19503">19503</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="8">8</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-11 07:20:00">2014-07-11 07:20:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-11 07:50:00">2014-07-11 07:50:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-11 07:20:00">2014-07-11 07:20:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-11 07:35:00">2014-07-11 07:35:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="15">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-4" data-row-id="4">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="4" data-row-id="4">4</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19504">19504</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="9">9</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-09 07:30:00">2014-07-09 07:30:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-09 07:45:00">2014-07-09 07:45:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-09 07:30:00">2014-07-09 07:30:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-09 07:39:00">2014-07-09 07:39:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="9">9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-3" data-row-id="3">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="3" data-row-id="3">3</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19505">19505</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="10">10</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-08 07:00:00">2014-07-08 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-08 07:50:00">2014-07-08 07:50:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-08 07:00:00">2014-07-08 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-08 07:50:00">2014-07-08 07:50:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="50">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-2" data-row-id="2">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="2" data-row-id="2">2</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19506">19506</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="11">11</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-03 15:15:00">2014-07-03 15:15:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-03 15:25:00">2014-07-03 15:25:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-03 15:15:00">2014-07-03 15:15:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-03 15:25:00">2014-07-03 15:25:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="10">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-1" data-row-id="1">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="1" data-row-id="1">1</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19508">19508</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="12">12</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtmemutlu">dtmemutlu</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-02 07:00:00">2014-07-02 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-02 07:45:00">2014-07-02 07:45:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-02 07:00:00">2014-07-02 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-02 07:35:00">2014-07-02 07:35:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="35">35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-6" data-row-id="6">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="6" data-row-id="6">6</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19607">19607</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="15">15</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-15 16:39:00">2014-07-15 16:39:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-15 16:48:00">2014-07-15 16:48:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="IRIS &amp; Dış CC">IRIS &amp; Dış CC</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="9">9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-10" data-row-id="10">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="10" data-row-id="10">10</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19614">19614</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="16">16</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtesari">dtesari</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Completed">Completed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Interruptive Work">Interruptive Work</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Planned">Planned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 07:00:00">2014-07-17 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 07:50:00">2014-07-17 07:50:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 07:00:00">2014-07-17 07:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 07:20:00">2014-07-17 07:20:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="CRM">CRM</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="20">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-9" data-row-id="9">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="9" data-row-id="9">9</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19667">19667</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="18">18</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 17:37:00">2014-07-16 17:37:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 19:21:00">2014-07-16 19:21:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="OTT">OTT</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="104">104</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-11" data-row-id="11">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="11" data-row-id="11">11</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19668">19668</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19">19</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 08:00:00">2014-07-17 08:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 10:44:00">2014-07-17 10:44:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="ADK">ADK</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="164">164</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-12" data-row-id="12">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="12" data-row-id="12">12</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19669">19669</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="20">20</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 08:00:00">2014-07-17 08:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 09:20:00">2014-07-17 09:20:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="ADK">ADK</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="100">100</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="80">80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-13" data-row-id="13">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="13" data-row-id="13">13</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19669">19669</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="20">20</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 08:00:00">2014-07-17 08:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 09:20:00">2014-07-17 09:20:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="IRIS &amp; Dış CC">IRIS &amp; Dış CC</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="100">100</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="80">80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="playsql-0-8" data-row-id="8">
            <th class="id-column" data-position="8" data-row-id="8">8</th>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="19671">19671</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="21">21</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Availibility">Service Availibility</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="dtitesaygivar">dtitesaygivar</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Fixed">Fixed</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Service Interruption">Service Interruption</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Unplanned">Unplanned</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="Minor">Minor</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-16 11:00:00">2014-07-16 11:00:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="2014-07-17 12:59:00">2014-07-17 12:59:00</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="OTT">OTT</td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="nul"><span class="not-a-value">-</span></td>
            <td class="data-cell" data-editor-value="1559">1559</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>


<thead><tr class="sortableHeader">
<th data-editor-value="ID" title="ID" data-column_label="" data-renderer_key="id-renderer" data-column="0" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner"><a href="/confluence/playsql-base-plugin/query-editor.action?key=PDOQA&amp;queryId=35">&nbsp;</a></div></th>

<th data-editor-value="ISSUE_ID" title="ISSUE_ID" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="1" class="sortableHeader tablesorter-headerSortDown"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">ISSUE_ID</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="ISSUENUM" title="ISSUENUM" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="2" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">ISSUENUM</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="PROJECT" title="PROJECT" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="3" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PROJECT</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="REPORTER" title="REPORTER" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="4" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">REPORTER</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="RESOLUTION" title="RESOLUTION" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="5" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">RESOLUTION</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="ISSUE_TYPE" title="ISSUE_TYPE" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="6" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">ISSUE_TYPE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="INTERRUPTION_TYPE" title="INTERRUPTION_TYPE" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="7" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">INTERRUPTION_TYPE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="SEVERITY" title="SEVERITY" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="8" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">SEVERITY</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="PLANNED_START_DATE" title="PLANNED_START_DATE" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="9" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PLANNED_START_DATE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="PLANNED_END_DATE" title="PLANNED_END_DATE" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="10" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PLANNED_END_DATE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="REAL_START_DATE" title="REAL_START_DATE" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="11" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">REAL_START_DATE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="REAL_END_DATE" title="REAL_END_DATE" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="12" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">REAL_END_DATE</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="PRODUCT" title="PRODUCT" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="13" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PRODUCT</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS" title="NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="14" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="COST" title="COST" data-renderer_key="string-renderer" data-column="15" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">COST</div></th>
<th data-editor-value="DIFF_MINUTES" title="DIFF_MINUTES" data-renderer_key="read-only-default-renderer" data-column="16" class="sortableHeader"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">DIFF_MINUTES</div></th>

</tr></thead><thead>

</thead></table>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to Get Product column values.I couldnt add a pic. ,stackoverflow didnt allow me .

Comment: What does "Get Product column values" mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available. It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another small implementation:

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
 var currentTr = $(this).children()
 var productTd = currentTr[13]; //product column number
 console.log("Product: ",$(productTd).attr("data-editor-value"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLZLq/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `data()` to get each of the `data-*` attributes.

or you can use `text()` to retrieve the value of the element.

Here's a sample:

```
// Iterate through every table row
$("tr").each(function(){

   // Iterate through each table data within row
   $(this).find("td").each(function(){

      // Get the values
      var data_value = $(this).data("editor-value");
      var data_text_value = $(this).text();
   });

});
```