# How can i delete the the particular ul tag based on id in a div?

Tags: jquery

On click of a button i need to remove a particular ul tag

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/54/

This is my code

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap" id="result">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
             <h3>Heading 1<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon" data_attr="123" >Edit</a></h3>

            <ul data-role="listview" labellistulid="48" class="labellistUL ui-listview">
                <li class="labellist   ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 25/- Delivery Charges 21.11</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightlable"> <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" data_vendor_id="5000821693" data_loc_name="Location1" data_ven_availability_id="46">Remove</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul data-role="listview" labellistulid="47" class="labellistUL ui-listview">
                <li class="labellist   ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 25/- Delivery Charges 21.11</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightlable"> <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" data_vendor_id="5000821693" data_loc_name="Location1" data_ven_availability_id="46">Remove</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function (event) {
    var labellist_id = $(this).closest('.labellistUL').attr('labellistULid');

    deltethislabel(labellist_id);

});

function deltethislabel(labellist_id) {
    // do an ajax call if its success then remove it 
    $("#result").find("#" + labellist_id + " .labellistUL").remove();
}
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `$(this).closest('.labellistUL').remove()` in the click handler... no need to get `labellist_id`

Comment: @ArunPJohny , i have to delete based on the Ajax result , so can't use this .

Comment: @Kiran I don't see any Ajax requests in your code. And you have already found element: `$(this).closest('.labellistUL')`. What is the point to search it once more?

Comment: @Regent , Ajax code s present in my actual application , so for fiddle i have put a comment based on that .

Comment: @Kiran and how can we suggest something not seeing important part of code? Right now, based on your code, Arun P Johny's solution sounds like the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute equals selector as suggested above, or pass the ul reference to the delete method like

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function (event) {
    var $ul = $(this).closest('.labellistUL');

    deltethislabel($ul);

});

function deltethislabel($ul) {
    var labellist_id = $ul.attr('labellistULid');

    // do an ajax call if its success then remove it 
    $ul.remove();
}
```

Comment: @Regent yes, it should be

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/55/)**.

Just use jQuery [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) & [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) like this:

```
$('.removerestaurant').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: `.parent().parent().parent()` is inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` on the `a` to find the nearest `.labellistUL` element, and remove it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('.labellistUL').remove();
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/58/)

Also note that creating non-standard attributes (ie. `labellistulid`) means your page is invalid. This can cause issues with your UI and JavaScript code. If you need to store additional data with an element, use a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Thanks , but i have to delete based on the id .

Comment: But you have no elements of matching ids in the HTML, hence why it doesn't work. This achieves the same behaviour without that need.

Comment: @Kiran if you want to select elements based on IDs, first of all **add** IDs to your elements.

Comment: Even though i added id's i couldn't able to do delete on that .

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing your js with this:

`$( "a.removerestaurant" ).click(function() {
    alert('labellistulid: '+$(this).closest('ul').attr('labellistulid'));
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();
});`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/62/)

Answer (score 0):

Below I get all UL tags and search into by the desired atribute, when found, remove itseld using parentElement.

I didn't use JQuery, so you can change it to fit your needs using any suite you want.

```
<html>
<script>
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) !== null)
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}

  function Remove(labellistulid){
    //Credits for this function in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available
    elements = getAllElementsWithAttribute('labellistulid');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      if (elements[i].getAttribute("labellistulid") == labellistulid) {     
        elements[i].parentElement.removeChild(elements[i]);
      }
    }    
  }
</script>
<body>
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap" id="result">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
             <h3>Heading 1<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon" data_attr="123" >Edit</a></h3>

            <ul data-role="listview" labellistulid="48" class="labellistUL ui-listview">
                <li class="labellist   ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 24/- Delivery Charges 21.11</p>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="Remove(48)" class="rightlable"> <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" data_vendor_id="5000821693" data_loc_name="Location1" data_ven_availability_id="46">Remove</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul data-role="listview" labellistulid="47" class="labellistUL ui-listview">
                <li class="labellist   ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 25/- Delivery Charges 21.11</p>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="Remove(47)" class="rightlable"> <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" data_vendor_id="5000821693" data_loc_name="Location1" data_ven_availability_id="46">Remove</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```