# Check if angular is already loaded and overwrite it with recent version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I am working on one very complex functionality in SharePoint 2013 where I need to include angular code as a webpart in pages.

**There are several scenarios like,**

1. Masterpage (Shared Layout for header and footer and rest of the stuff) may already contain angularJS file (that can be older version as well).
2. When we add a web part with angular code in it, I also include angular script reference in it since we never know if master page / shared layout has angular reference or not.

**What I tried to reproduce similar situation -**

-Included Angular script twice.. First one is older Angular, second is latest one. Code fails to work with following error -

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionangular.js:26130 (anonymous function)
```

**What I want to achieve -**

I want to check if master page already has reference to Angular, even if it has, ignore it and prefer the reference I have given because my code will be modular and dependent on the script I want to include (latest one, most probably)

I know this sounds stupid but this is how it works with SharePoint Web parts.. I am sure there will be some way like `noConflict` in Angular..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if angularjs has already been loaded on the page, look for the **ng-app** attribute on any of the tags.

You may use this function:

```
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) !== null)
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}
```

Then,

```
getAllElementsWithAttribute('ng-app');
```

Refer this SO question

[Can I get elements by attribute selector when querySelectorAll is not available without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available)

It can help you detect the presence of angular.
Even I have a similar scenario and would like to know about how to find the angular version and load a recent one.