# finding elements containing specific attribute prefix

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if it's possible but I want to find elements according to their attribute name prefix. The attribute goes like this:

```
<div attName:someOtherValue="12"> </div>
```

It doesn't have to be necessarily on divs but it does follow the above pattern.

### **Update**

Ok, I forgot 2 important points regarding what I'm trying to accomlish:
 1. I can't use jQuery so I'll be using only native JS.
 2. 2. The par AFTER the colon changes so When I say I need to find according to an attribute prefix I CAN'T use the part after the colon but only the part before the colon (or including the colon)

Comment: Check [this anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/3790486) i think it what you need to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a common class for all this elements:

```
<div class="yourClass 12"> </div>
```

Then you can refer to all like:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass");
```

If you cannot modify the class of elements, with JQuery you can make a pattern:

```
$("div:regex(class, .yourClass*)")
```

If you want to "simulate" a pattern, you can select all elements with

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(*);
```

Iterating over elements you can get matching ones analizing `class` or `attribute` simply with `String::indexof()`

Comment: thanks for the comment Jordi. I'll consider using a class however I can't use jQuery (I updated my post)

Comment: All my answer is `javascript` only part to select by pattern the className is `JQuery`, so I think if will fit your needs, let me know if you get stucked somewhere... ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the html5 data attribute

```
<div data-theNameYouWant="someValue">xpto</div>
```

and with jQuery

```
$("*").data("theNameYouWant", function(){
    //do your stuff
});
//in case you want a log of that value
console.log($("*").data("theNameYouWant"));
//this will return a log (in browser console), with all the elements values that contains the attribute "data-theNameYouWant"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following to match all elements with attribute you've mentioned

```
$('[attName\\:someOtherValue="12"]')
```

As you've `:` in the selector, you need to escape it with `\\`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xiyotapugi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

The same in pure JavaScript:

```js
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[attName\\:someOtherValue="12"]');
  for(var i =0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.add("spaner");
  }
```

```css
.spaner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div attName:someOtherValue="12"> </div>
 <p attName:someOtherValue="12"> </p>
 <span attName:someOtherValue="12"> hi </span>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment mohamedrias. It would have been optimal but I can only search the first part before the colon sign (on including the colon sign). The part after the colon changes.

Answer (score 0):

A custom function here that gets the element's `attributes` property and rolls through that looking for the given substring, if found returns an object with the matching attribute name and value.

*Usage:*

```
var attribute_object = match_attribute(element, key_substring)
```

*Example:*

```
<div attName:someOtherValue="12"> </div>

<script>

function match_attribute (elem, key) {
    var attributes = elem.attributes
    var obj = {}

    Array.prototype.slice.call(attributes).forEach(function(attribute) {
        if ( -1 !== attribute.name.indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) ) {
            obj = { name: attribute.name, value: attribute.value }
        }
    })
    return obj
}

console.log(match_attribute(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0], 'attName:'))
// Object {name: "attname:someothervalue", value: "12"}

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/14Ly3vps/)