# How can I change the label for css style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a checkbox with label.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="comment" id="abc1" value="the value." 
 onclick="createOrder()"><label for="abc1" onclick="createOrder()" 
 title="title"> onscreen text for this checkbox </label>
```

In a javascript function, I want to change the appearance of the input.  Here is an example that works (changes the element's visibility) but is not what I want to do:

```
if (n !== -1) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

However, I don't want to make it invisible.  I want to change the text color of the words associated with the checkbox ("onscreen text for this checkbox")  The text would change from the default black to grey.

I don't know how to change the "label for" style.  Can anyone help change the javascript?  The result would simply change the color of the text.

Comment: Why do you have onClick on `label`? Whats `id` here, is it the `label` id?

Comment: Clicking the text next to the checkbox will also check the checkbox.  id is the input id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the code you're trying works so to target next node, you can use [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

```
if (n !== -1) {
   document.getElementById(id).nextSibling.style.color= "#c8c8c8"; //color you need"
}
else{
  document.getElementById(id).nextSibling.style.color= "#fefefe"; //Default color
}
```

Comment: This looks simple and straight-forward, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I am using the most current Chrome.  Could it be because the label doesn't have a predefined style?

Comment: No, it should work whether label has predefined style or not. Can you post full code so that i can look again into it?

Comment: You have all the relevant code.  I check a variable n and based on the result I want to change the id.  My given code works to turn the element invisible.  So, it works to that point.  I want to replace the visibility code with a color change.  Perhaps the CSS style sheet is overriding it?

Comment: `nextSibling` might return you a text node and not the label. use `nextElementSibling` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like using jQuery:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(ee){ 
 $("#abc1").click(function(){   
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {       
         $(this).next().css({"color": "Red"});
     }else
     {
         $(this).next().css({"color": "black"});
     }
});
```

});

HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="comment" id="abc1" value="the value." ><label for="abc1" title="title"> onscreen text for this checkbox </label>
```

This should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it can easily be achieved, doesnt matter where the label is located or how many are there.

there is an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/3406576) that shows how to get elements by their attributes.

lets take the function from that answer, adjust it and use it for your question:

```js
//get all labels with for=abc1 attribute
el=getLabelByForAttribute("abc1");

//loop through those labels and change their style
el.forEach(function(elem,idx){
    elem.style["color"]="grey";
});

function getLabelByForAttribute(a)
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  //get all labels in the document
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
  {
    //if those labels have the required 'for' attribute
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute("for") ==a)
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="comment" id="abc1" value="the value." onclick="createOrder()">
<label for="abc1" onclick="createOrder()" title="title">onscreen text for this checkbox</label>
```