# How to getElementsByTagName when elements are prepared for being an array in their name

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get an array of elements with javascript or jQuery when the elements I want are a set with the same name prepared for being an array once I submit the form.

Much more understandable with the code:

```
<form>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input name='ciudades[]' id="cb_0" type='checkbox' style="display: none" checked="checked" value="ALICANTE_AER">ALICANTE_AER</input>
    <input name='ciudades[]' id="cb_1" type='checkbox' style="display: none" checked="checked" value="MALAGA_AER">MALAGA_AER</input>
    <input name='ciudades[]' id="cb_2" type='checkbox' style="display: none" checked="checked" value="MALLORCA_AER">MALLORCA_AER</input>
    <input name='ciudades[]' id="cb_3" type='checkbox' style="display: none" checked="checked" value="VALENCIA_AER">VALENCIA_AER</input>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

I've tried to get an array with all the elements named 'ciudades[]' with these two ways unsuccesfully:

```
var cb_ciudades = document.getElementsByTagName('ciudades[]');
```

and

```
var cb_ciudades = document.getElementsByTagName('ciudades');
```

but I'm ending with an empty array in both cases. How could it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` works by **tag name**, e.g. `input` or `div` or `span`, not the `name` attribute.

If you want to get those elements by their `name`, you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="ciudades[]"]');
```

`querySelectorAll` is supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Or as you've tagged your question `jquery`:

```
var $list = $('input[name="ciudades[]"]');
```

Comment: thank you for clarifying, so I totally misunderstood the getElementsByTagName method :O

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the elements by attribute as `ciudades[]` is value of name attribute. however you have used get by tag name method. You can get them using jquery:

```
$('[name="ciudades[]"]')
```

If you want the solution in javascript then refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342661/1719752

Answer (score 0):

**javascipt**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var myElements = [];
for(var i =0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') == 'ciudades[]'){
        myElements.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[name="ciudades[]"]')
```