# Should I not use data attributes in html?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I am coding a C# forms application that lets a user add custom html nodes to a html webpage. I have some javascript code that selects a html node to execute specific code for objects such as a jQuery ui slider.

To identify html nodes, I need to store an attribute in the tag that identifies the tag.

I am new to writing html code, and as such, I would like to ask if there is any reason why I should not use data attributes for tags? Are there any limitations are disadvantages that I should be aware of?

Here is some example code that I have currently working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div data-customwebpagelayout-name='slider-increments'>
    <div data-customwebpageobject-name='slider-increments'></div>
</div>

<p data-customwebpageobject-output-name='slider-increments'>1</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: In what way do you need to “identify” those nodes? Any reason why you would not simply use a `class` to be able to “identify” (and easily _select_) those elements …?

Comment: If you need unique identifiers for HTML nodes, you can assign an `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to identify and select HTML tags is with either `class` or `id`.

If there is only going to be one of something on a page, you should use `id`. It looks like you have multiple of the same thing you want to identify, so I'd use `class` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="customwebpagelayout slider-increments" >
    <div class="customwebpageobject slider-increments"></div>
</div>

<p class="customwebpageobject slider-increments">1</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Then you could select the nodes with javascript like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("slider-increments");
```

or if you decide to use jQuery:

```
$(".slider-increments");
```

Data attributes are more of a pain to work with:

Raw Javascript [(code adapted from code in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/1556343):

```
var matchingElements = [];
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++){
  if (allElements[i].getAttribute('data-customwebpagelayout-name') !== null){
    // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
    matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
  }
}
//use matchingElements;
```

jQuery:

```
$("*[data-customwebpagelayout-name='data-customwebpagelayout-name']");
```