# Another greasemonkey login script

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, autologin

For my first go at writing a greasemonkey script I decided to try creating an autologin script.

The page I am trying to login to is built as;

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-reactid=".0.0.1:$0.1.1:$input" placeholder="Username"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" data-reactid=".0.0.1:$0.2">
<input class="form-control" type="password" data-reactid=".0.0.1:$0.2.1:$input" placeholder="Password"></input>
</div>
<button class="btn-block btn btn-lg" data-reactid=".0.0.1:$0.3" type="button" disabled="">
```

The button becomes enabled when you populate the username/password values. So far my script looks like:

```
var name = "foo";
var pass = "bar";
document.getElementByTagName ([placeholder="Username"]).value = name;
document.getElementByTagName ([placeholder="Password"]).value = pass;
var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
document.getElementByClassName('btn-block btn btn-lg btn-primary').dispatchEvent (evt);
```

...but this doesn't seem to actually push data into the username/password fields. I added some alert statements to basically step through and it looks like it dies when I first use  document.getElementByTagName

Comment: Did you possibly mean `getElement*s*ByTagName` and `getElement*s*ByClassName`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` - note that "Elements" is plural in those function names.

That being said, I don't believe an attribute selector works with `getElementsByTagName`.  You could write your own function that achieves a similar goal (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/3076272)) but you're probably better off using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```
var name = "foo";
var pass = "bar";
document.querySelector('[placeholder="Username"]').value = name;
document.querySelector('[placeholder="Password"]').value = pass;
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.querySelector('.btn-block, .btn, .btn-lg, .btn-primary').dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Note that `document.querySelector` returns the first result that matches the query - make sure that there is only one thing that matches it.