# Return price from HTML element using JS

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Using this view-page-source has my reference http://www.ebest.cl/audifonos-alta-fidelidad-house-of-marley-revolution.html

I am trying to return the "3355" from this div using Javascript.

1. I want return this in the Chrome developer tools console first.

document.getElementsByClassName("data-product-id");

When I execute this I return an empty array. []

1. I want to be able to return this in a google tag manager variable.
    I write the code once I can at least test and return it in the console.

Thanks!
Spencer

Comment: that is definitely not a class name

Comment: A possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does not return an array. It returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), a array-like object. It is an important distinction. In addition to the other reasons array-like objects are not the same as arrays, HTMLCollections in particular are different in that they are a *live collection*. If the DOM changes the content of your collection might change even *after* you queried for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a data-* attribute, not a className. I went through the trouble of finding the child that has that data-attribute instead of directly referencing the correct node, since I (and possibly you) have no idea if the `yotpo bottomline` class will be available every time, so I put more faith in the `product-shop` className being available. If there are multiple products on the page, you'll only get the first ID. Extending to all ID's is trivial.

```
var productID = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName('product-shop')[0].childNodes
    ).reduce(function (acc, child) {
        var att = (child.nodeName === 'DIV') ? child.getAttribute('data-product-id') : false;
        if (att) acc = att;
        return acc;
    }, '');
```