# How to select text of the two elements with contentEditable = true?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask, how can I select text of the two HTML elements, which property contentEditable is set to true. When I start to select text with mouse in one element, the selection ends within it's range. Never reach the second element.

I tried to apply also "user-select" property, but without effect.

here is snippet.

```html
<body>
<div contentEditable = true style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top:10px; width:100px; height:200px; border: 3px solid #73AD21;">
Donec tempus, nisi a pharetra placerat, diam nisi aliquam elit, a consectetur magna enim sed ligula. 
</div>

<div contentEditable = true style="position:absolute; left: 130px; top:10px; width:100px; height:200px; border: 3px solid #73AD21;">
The oldest browsers support only one way of registering event handlers, the way invented by Netscape. 
</div>
</body>
```

thanx a lot

Comment: if you must use pure javascript see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/3574819 . otherwise use a library like jquery or something similar

Comment: @FuzzyTree, I couldn't get the relation. How is that answer going to help?

Comment: @ArmanOzak it provides a function that lets op select all elements by attribute (in this case contentEditable)

Comment: @FuzzyTree, the question is not about selectors. It is about text selection.

Comment: @FuzzyTree, of course, javascript is the last resort, probably there is not nice trick to solve this. But I feel, it may be pretty nasty programming. I hope, that something usable might exist.

Comment: @lyborko ah ok, I was thinking javascript because of the tag. anyway, no harm done, that's what comments are there for :)

Comment: @FuzzyTree, ouch... sorry for messing it up...  my fault... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap these `<div>`s inside another `<div>` and make it `contentEditable="true"` instead of these two.

```
<body>
  <div contentEditable="true">
    <div style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top:10px; width:100px; height:200px; border: 3px solid #73AD21;">
Donec tempus, nisi a pharetra placerat, diam nisi aliquam elit, a consectetur magna enim sed ligula.</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left: 130px; top:10px; width:100px; height:200px; border: 3px solid #73AD21;">
The oldest browsers support only one way of registering event handlers, the way invented by Netscape.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/xecofihili/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: Perfect... :-) It does exactly what I asked, but I see unexpected results too... Thanx a lot...