# Chrome extension CSP sha-256 hash for inline event script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to implement a content-security-policy to enable inline handlers execution in chrome extension using `sha-256` hashes for each inline event script.

But I can not get this to work: I extracted all the inlines and calculated hashes, so that my `content_security_policy` now looks like this:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-Zy8+Ft7FDcIkrTYgl2BKmEW5XD97XustxKPceyLSioQ=' 'sha256-YNkUpNj1B2/FuE2RmwQf40OIO5rH69xQbG5AAxwshrA=' 'sha256-Pmun4RTarna683hWYftYdXPERPfEVV5fB+qvqh3xnmg=' ... ... 'sha256-RoSxVuvjYKDbU5f+aUEw02rEM9e2Lp9Hz/+rxbp6OMw='; object-src 'self'"`

for example, for `onclick="w2ui['grid'].click('1', event);"` I get `sha256-Zy8+Ft7FDcIkrTYgl2BKmEW5XD97XustxKPceyLSioQ=`

[The docs state](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script) that this is a supported method but it still throws errors

`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-Zy8+Ft7FDcIkrTYgl2BKmEW5XD97XustxKPceyLSioQ=' 'sha256-YNkUpNj1B2/FuE2RmwQf40OIO5rH69xQbG5AAxwshrA=' 'sha256-Pmun4RTarna683hWYftYdXPERPfEVV5fB+qvqh3xnmg=' ... ... Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Is it a known bug or I am just misusing the concept?

Comment: Chrome normally shows the sha256 value you require but you've just shown ... in your error message. Did Chrome calculate the same hash value as you did?

Comment: no - chrome shows literally `Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Answer (score 2):

The answer here seems that chrome - for some reason - does not support inline events hashing at all; I was able to work around this by pre-evaluating all the inlines using the `'unsafe-eval'` permission:

```js
var events = ["onclick", "onmouseover", "onmouseout", "onmousedown",
"onmouseup", "onscroll", "oncontextmenu", "onmousewheel", "ondblclick"];
function vulcanize_inlines() {
    for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
        var els = getAllElementsWithAttribute(events[i]);
        for(var j=0;j<els.length;j++) {
            var fun = eval("(function a(){"+els[j].getAttribute(events[i])+"})");
            els[j].removeAttribute(events[i]);
            els[j][events[i]] = fun;
        }
    }
}
```

and adding this to `.onload`:

```js
vulcanize_inlines();
var target = document.body;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    vulcanize_inlines();
});
var config = { /*attributes: true,*/ childList: true, 
   characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

`getAllElementsWithAttribute` I used from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/2659616)

Comment: If an attacker is able to inject HTML onto a page, wouldn't this allow them to effectively piggyback an inline event along with it?