# shinyBS observe toggling of bsCollapsePanel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, shinybs

my question relates to observing the event of toggling and untoggling of the header in bsCollapsePanel in shinyBS.

Lets consider following following app as an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
      updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel 1")
    }))
    observeEvent(input$styleSelect, ({
      updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", style = list("Panel 1" = input$styleSelect))
    }))
    output$randomNumber <- reactive(paste0('some random number'))
  }


ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel 1 using <code>updateCollapse</code>."),
                 actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                 selectInput("styleSelect", "Select style for Panel 1",
                             c("default", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "success"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                 bsCollapsePanel("Panel 1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                 "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                 "the sidebar.", style = "info")
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput('randomNumber')
    )
  )
)

app = shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the app to be able to print a random number (using R shiny reactivity) in the `verbatimTextOutput('randomNumber')` field every time I open `bsCollapsePanel` by clicking on `Panel 1` header.

I was thinking that it may be possible using `shinyjs` package but have not found many examples of these two packages used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you want, but this might be close. These are the additions:

- Added an `observeEvent` to monitor your `Panel 1` header.
- Added a `reactiveValues` to hold the "random number"
- Incremented that value in the above `observeEvent` handler when `Panel 1` is pushed.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(number=0)
  observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
    updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel 1")
  }))
  observeEvent(input$styleSelect, ({
    updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", style = list("Panel 1" = input$styleSelect))
  }))
  observeEvent(input$collapseExample, ({
    rv$number <- rv$number+1
  }))
  output$randomNumber <- reactive(rv$number)
}


ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel 1 using <code>updateCollapse</code>."),
                 actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                 selectInput("styleSelect", "Select style for Panel 1",
                           c("default", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "success"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                 bsCollapsePanel("Panel 1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                 "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                 "the sidebar.", style = "info")
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput('randomNumber')
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution. Even though after running it I realized that I want the number to change after I would close panel as well. But since I only mentioned opening the panel in my question and you were the first one to answer it would make sense for me to accept it.

Comment: I would appreciate that. And feel free to post another question around additional requirements, I am sure someone will address it - including me if I find the time.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Mike Wise was faster than me :)
If for some reason my solution is also helpful let me know otherwise i delete it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel1 using <code>updateCollapse</code>."),
                 actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                 selectInput("styleSelect", "Select style for Panel1",
                             c("default", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "success"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                 bsCollapsePanel("Panel1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                 "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                 "the sidebar.", style = "info", id = "me23")
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput('randomNumber')
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
    updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel1")
  }))
  observeEvent(input$styleSelect, ({
    updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", style = list("Panel1" = input$styleSelect))
  }))

  observe({
    runjs("function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute){
              var matchingElements = [];
              var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
              for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
              {
              if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) !== null)
              {
              // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
              matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
              }
              }
              return matchingElements;
              };
              ahref = getAllElementsWithAttribute('data-toggle');
              ahref[0].onclick = function() { 
                var nmbr = Math.random();
                Shiny.onInputChange('randomNumber', nmbr);
              };
          ")
  })
  output$randomNumber <- reactive(paste0(input$randomNumber))
}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Javascript code you can find here: 
[Get elements by attribute when querySelectorAll is not available without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/get-elements-by-attribute-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available-without-using-l)

Comment: I think it is useful code, albeit maybe overkill for this particular scenario. Might be more applicable to what he intends in the long run though.

Comment: i agree i also tried first working with `input$collapseExample` but somehow i seemed have to miss smthg as it didnt work for me. +1 for your more elegant solution :).

Comment: Ditto for your more interesting solution. Studying it actually, will certainly be able to use that someday.

Comment: Brilliant solution. I like the combination of shinyjs and shinyBS. Definitely will be useful for me.