# Is it possible to change the fill color of an svg chart using javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the backend, the following graph is being generated:

```html
<svg width="911.4" height="300">
     <g transform="translate(40,20)">
     <g>
     <g fill="#6d6e71">
     <rect x="1" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="66" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="131" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="196" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="261" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="326" y="159" height="21" width="62" fill="#6d6e71"></rect>
     <rect x="391" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="456" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="521" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="586" y="161" height="19" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="651" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="716" y="166" height="14" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="781" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     </g>
     </g>
     </svg>
```

Is there a way I could change the `fill="#6d6e71"` value in the frontend just using javascript?

Comment: Is the SVG within the page, or is it an image element that points to an SVG file?

Comment: @Archer it's within the page :)

Answer (score 3):

With `setAttribute()` you can change fill. See [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Use

```
//find first element with "someAttr" attribute
document.querySelector('[someAttr]')
```

or

```
//find all elements with "someAttr" attribute
document.querySelectorAll('[someAttr]')
```

to find elements with an specific attribute.

[See SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/get-elements-by-attribute-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available-without-using-l)

```js
var elment = document.querySelector('[fill]');
elment.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");

var rect = document.querySelector('svg g rect[fill]')

rect.setAttribute("fill", "#ffff00");
```

```html
<svg width="911.4" height="300">
     <g transform="translate(40,20)">
     <g>
     <g fill="#6d6e71">
     <rect x="1" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="66" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="131" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="196" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="261" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="326" y="159" height="21" width="62" fill="#6d6e71"></rect>
     <rect x="391" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="456" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="521" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="586" y="161" height="19" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="651" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="716" y="166" height="14" width="62"></rect>
     <rect x="781" y="180" height="0" width="62"></rect>
     </g>
     </g>
     </svg>
```

Comment: Was just wondering again if it's possible to change different fills? I basically have five  fill="#6d6e71" with different color values and I want to change these color values with different values again :| @MrMaavin

Comment: YOu can get only the first element with `document.querySelector('svg g')` and the second element with `document.querySelector('svg g rect[fill]')`

Answer (score 0):

Both element with fill can be changed. You need to select it and change the "fill" attribute like this:

Change global "fill" attribute:

```
var elment = document.querySelector('svg g');
elment.setAttribute("fill",[color]);
```

Change inner "rect" element's "fill" attribute:

```
var elment = document.querySelector('svg g rect[fill]');
elment.setAttribute("fill",[color]);
```

[color] need to thange to color value, for example: #123456
Is there any other element, where you need to change the fill?
If possible, the jQuery can be usefull to use $.each to change the elements "fill" attribute as you wish.

Comment: he asked for a javascript solution.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the `<g>` tag can receive `id` or `class` attribute...those are which you will have to change with js.

Sample:.

```
​.blue {
    fill: blue;
}​
​.green {
    fill: green;
}​
```

Then
`<g class="blue" id="my-path">`

Them you change the `class` of `<g>` to `green` with js.
`document.getElementById('my-path').classList.remove('blue')`
`document.getElementById('my-path').classList.add('green')`